# Why does my Stored Procedure return NULL in the below query?

Tags: mysql, sql, store

I have created a table and add some columns and now I want it to output `s_scourse` as "B.Tech" when the subject is "Computer Science".
But it is showing null. Why???

These are my sample data:

```
create table student(name varchar(50),age int,subject varchar(100));

insert into student values("Tanmay",18,"MAths"),("Rani",19,"Computer Science"),("Rose",20,"Computer Application");
delimiter
```

and this is my procedure:

```
create procedure get_students(in subject_name varchar(50),out s_scourse varchar(50))
begin
declare sub varchar(50);
select subject from student
where subject=subject_name;
if sub="Computer Science"
then set s_scourse="B.tech";
end if;
end//
delimiter ;
call get_students("Computer Science",@s_scourse);
select @s_scourse;
```

Comment: You have never assigned value to 'sub' and still using it in if statement sub="Computer Science", so if block will never get executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to use `INTO` to assign value to variable:

```
select subject 
INTO sub
from student
where subject=subject_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have s_scourse as an output variable for the stored procedure, the code can be simplified without declaring the local variable 'sub'. A simple case..when statement will suffice:

```
delimiter //
create procedure get_students(in subject_name varchar(50),out s_scourse varchar(50))
begin
select (case when subject_name="Computer Science" then "B.tech" else "Not B.tech" end) into s_scourse 
from student2
where subject=subject_name;
end//
delimiter ;
call get_students("Computer Science",@s_scourse);
select @s_scourse;
```

In the case where the subject input is "Computer Science" the output variable will have "B.tech" as its value. For other subjects(in the table you created), I set the default as "Not B.tech" . You can change it as per your requirements.

Comment: IT can be an alternative, but I am doing it only for if-then logic. By the way thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the value to the variable like `sub:=subject`

```
declare sub varchar(50);

select sub:=subject from student
where subject=subject_name;

if sub="Computer Science"
then set s_scourse="B.tech";
end if;
```